# Insert values to mysql Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-insert

It gives this error:

> "*java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).* "

This is the code:

```
public void insertData(int id,String name, String status, String age){



     String sql = "INSERT INTO student_table (id,name,satus,age) VALUES  (id,name,status,age)";

     try (Connection conn1 = this.connects();PreparedStatement Prepst= conn1.prepareStatement(sql)){

     Prepst.setInt(1, id);
     Prepst.setString(2, name);
     Prepst.setString(3, status);
     Prepst.setString(4, age);
     Prepst.executeUpdate();

     }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);

      }
```

If I   change  the parameter index to another value i.e.:

```
Prepst.setInt(0, id);
```

then it gives this error:

> *" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ). "*

----UPDATE -----

I inserted this code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO student_table (id,name,satus,age) VALUES  (?,?,?,?)";
```

It produces the same:

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQIvS.png)

Table Structure:

[image: HERE]

Comment: Please have a look at Java naming conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: The version with `(?,?,?,?)` is correct, but the first parameter is at position 1, not 0.

Comment: ok sorry my bad for that i was trying different ways. After correcting it it gives this --> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'satus' in 'field list'

Comment: could you send me the table structure/schema ?

Comment: @KlaydPro Maybe `status`, not `satus`? Anyway, your question is answered. Please don't extend it with "help me debug my code until I get the correct result" comments.

Comment: ok thank you all !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL expression

```
INSERT INTO student_table (id,name,satus,age) VALUES  (id,name,status,age)
```

actually does not have any parameters. Try with:

```
INSERT INTO student_table (id,name,satus,age) VALUES  (?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: @KlaydPro Please read JavaDocs of [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt-int-int-). In `PreparedStatement` indexing of parameters starts with 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public void insertData(int id,String name, String status, String age){



     String sql = "INSERT INTO student_table (id,name,satus,age) VALUES  (?,?,?,?)";

     try (Connection conn1 = this.connection;PreparedStatement Prepst= conn1.prepareStatement(sql)){

     Prepst.setInt(1, id);
     Prepst.setString(2, name);
     Prepst.setString(3, status);
     Prepst.setString(4, age);
     Prepst.executeUpdate();

     }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);

      }
}
```